# Angular: Nested forms and inputs comming from templates

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, ng-template

My StepsComponent has a part that looks like this:

```
<form>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let step of steps">
        <form>
            <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="step.getTemplateRef()"></ng-container>
        </form>
    </ng-container>
</form>
```

"steps" is a queryList of custom directives, each of those directivs holds a templateRef that will contain inputs. This is an example of how I could call that steps component:

```
<app-steps>
    <ng-template [step]="1">
        <p>Step-1</p>
        <input type="text" required [ngModel]="testModel" />
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template [step]="2">
        <p>Step-2</p>
        <input type="text" required [ngModel]="testModel2" />
        <input type="text" required [ngModel]="testModel3" />
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template [step]="3">
        <p>Step-3</p>
        <input type="text" required [ngModel]="testModel4" />
    </ng-template>
</app-steps>
```

So there is a main form that wraps everything, then each steps create an additional nested form. The issue is that I need to be able to check, inside my steps component, the validity of all the forms (the numbers and content of I don't know in advance.)

I have no idea how to do that. I don't think I can use form builder or create form groups because I don't have access to the inputs, since they come from an outside template...

I've tried putting input-output NgModels on my nested forms and dynamically giving them names but I get an error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with name: [myformname]

Comment: Is your initial form code pasted corectly? I see there's an open string in the ng-for that ends a couple lines later.

Comment: my bad, it was not pasted properly.